# Counting in an ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

***UPDATED CODE***

I'm trying to figure out a way to count how often one value appears in an ArrayList.

```
System.out.println("Hand 1, Number of Clubs: " 
              + hands[0].frequency(hands[0], Card.Suit.CLUBS));
```

So in the above case i want to count how many "Clubs" are in hands[0].

```
public int frequency(Hand c, Suit suit){
    int count = 0;
    if(suit == suit) //need this to be "If suit (club) is present, count++)
            {
             count++;
            }    
    return count;
}
```

I'm drawing a blank.... If i change the method type to ArrayList then i cannot return "count"

hands[0] is created by:

```
    Hand[] hands = new Hand[4];
    for(int i=0; i<hands.length; i++) {
       hands[i]=new Hand();
       }
       for(int i=0; i<=Deck.size()+8; i++) {
          for(Hand hand:hands) {
             hand.addSingleCard(Deck.deal());
           }
       }
```

Comment: if(suit == suit) ? something missing here.

Comment: This will always return true: `if(suit == suit)`

Comment: I suggest you start with something which compiles.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It does compile. Although i have been playing around with it. 
hands[0] is an arrayList of cards (approximates 13 cards).
I want to pass the method the hands[0] arrayList and possibly a suit and it return an int of how many of that suit is present in the arrayList.

Comment: Another side note, calling the `ArrayList<Hand>` passed into your `countSuit()` method `suit` seems odd. Especially later when you have your `for` loop which says "for each hand in suit"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Collections.frequency`

You have this feature already available from [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html) class, in the [`frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object)) method.

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o)
```

That will return the number of occurrences of a specific object inside a [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

Mind that without providing a vaild [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method this won't work or at least won't work with the equality you have in mind, since Java does't know your meaning of equality.

Comment: I've attempted to use your method, however it only returns 1 count... maybe i'm overlooking something simple...